# Veutify: disable dropdown open when click in input fieldin autocomlete

Tags: autocomplete, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify with vue3.

How to disable open dropdown menu, when I click in input field in vuetify autocomplete?

I tried many v-autocomplete props, but it didn't help me :( Google also didn't help me unfortunately.

Comment: when would you want the menu to open instead?